# Android tabs inside activity

Tags: android-layout, tabs, android

I have a really nice design that I want to implement.
This design has tabs inside the activity, lets say in a LinearLayout under an image.
I could only find tabs on tabactivity or that contain whole activity.
Is this doable or should I change my design ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for this you can create a class which can extends **ActivityGroup**.

Here is the beautiful link for TabActivity with the example.

http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

Comment: TabActivity was deprecated in API level 13. You should use fragments instead now